# How to get CSS types for React / styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am getting this error in my styled component:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WordBreak | undefined'.
```

It is happening here:

```
type PropsType = {
  breakEverywhere?: boolean
  breakWord?: boolean
}

const Text = styled.p<PropsType>(props => ({
  wordBreak: getWordBreak(props),
}))

function getWordBreak(props: PropsType): string | undefined {
  if (props.breakWord) {
    return 'break-word'
  }
  if (props.breakEverywhere) {
    return 'break-all'
  }
}
```

It can be easily fixed by leaving off the type annotation `string | undefined` on the `getWordBreak` function. But how can I add a type annotation? It says `WordBreak`, but google searching for `WordBreak` type definitions doesn't yield any results, and no VSCode help. Any ideas?

The same sort of problem happens if I abstract away `textAlign` to in a similar way, it talks about `TextAlign` type. Looks like the [csstype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype) won't help either.

If I use this in the styled component:

```
textAlign: props.align ? TEXT_ALIGN[props.align] : undefined,
```

And I have this:

```
type AlignType = 'center' | 'end' | 'start'

const TEXT_ALIGN: Record<AlignType, string> = {
  center: 'center',
  end: 'right',
  start: 'left',
}
```

Then i get this:

```
Types of property 'textAlign' are incompatible.
  Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'TextAlign | undefined'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TextAlign | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

I can fix it with an untyped function instead:

```
function getTextAlign(align: AlignType) {
  switch (align) {
    case 'center':
      return 'center'
    case 'end':
      return 'right'
    default:
      return 'left'
  }
}
```

But that is ugly, how can I do it the `Record` way or a cleaner way? How can I get access to these types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks like the [csstype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype) won't help either.

Styled-components types are [based on csstype](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b2e2ad0e37d8ff55ba3507e141c7861815a6e374/types/styled-components/index.d.ts#L23), so you should be able to get what you need from there.

Type [`WordBreak`](https://github.com/frenic/csstype/blob/v3.1.1/index.d.ts#L19210) is in namespace [`Property`](https://github.com/frenic/csstype/blob/v3.1.1/index.d.ts#L18031) of `csstype`:

```
export namespace Property {
  // ...
  export type WordBreak = Globals | "break-all" | "break-word" | "keep-all" | "normal";
  // ...
}
```

Using it with your code sample:

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import { Property } from "csstype"

const Text2 = styled.p<PropsType>(props => ({
    wordBreak: getWordBreak2(props), // Okay
}))

function getWordBreak2(props: PropsType): Property.WordBreak | undefined { // Okay
    if (props.breakWord) {
        return 'break-word'
    }
    if (props.breakEverywhere) {
        return 'break-all'
    }
    return
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZxgTwDYFMAmcBmUIhwBESaWAtAMYGQB26tMCRAUKJLHAN5wAK+YdLGRwAvrnyEilBKUGsWKQXwEIAKsmUBebizj64AIyjoAhgGsAogDchyAO4ALIegD8ALiMQIGU7T0GxmbmAOrQmB5ePmb+oiws1LRIcGroAB7wOqQYmAB0YAA8-BBg6proAHwAFGCqcFoVcFVcAfr24QBCJhaeAOboMGFQmF3BNaoAlAA0cAD0s3CWUPhQnhrKAORIUMC0vRtwwAhwtBDwprLAvbSmhhhwMBAP5XAbQyPd5nAAPnAArrRMOgcLssBtcixRBMJvEcADKDBgBBaHB+oNOp9xiUEJ5iqV1ugJp5trtej9-oDgaDsDx5otltBPAA5M5wUyoVBwahAuBgUwwRzHEwwP5QFGmODWdl-dAQgyHHBNWrY3JBCzvCa6eXy4WilEbNXmcjtYYbVpic3ARVY0qqz42OxOFyalragy6sWvQ3kdmoM3yuJxBLI5KpDIAJnqiBQOXyRVUBOqytK9UazXNJo+wT6A3eows4ZtCGmcwWAHlzKZkJDobD4YjkajcxjgoXkziVNiCUTO4JhLk859yQCgSD6DTS3AK1XLdb23bghqtW64B79d7M-6DHF5ValaoFxYHVAHM4TC7zTqBnqvZ8fRyt-od+7r2LIUA)

Comment: Great! How did you possibly find that? Searching everywhere didn't have any results for me.

Comment: Habit of looking into source/types. It is true that csstype file is huge, making it difficult to navigate. And TS error message may be lacking sometimes (here the namespace could have made a big difference).